# How to configure Proguard so that obfuscation works without code optimization?

Tags: proguard

Only obfuscation is needed. Settings in build.gradle:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Found that the `-dontoptimize` parameter is responsible for optimization. Added it to proguard-rules.pro. just a line:

```
-dontoptimize
```

It didn’t work, maybe the flag was added incorrectly?

Comment: How does the "optimization" turn into SQL?